Using titletoc with \addcontentsline
I would like to create sub-TOCs for chapters and add references for the chapters to the internal TOC of the PDF via \addcontentsline. I tried the following, but it results in an error after the second compilation run. What is the reason for this and how to solve this problem? The error seems to refer to the .plc file, but I can't see any problems there.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\startcontents

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Foo}

\printcontents{l}{1}{}

\section{Bar}

\end{document}

Note: I know that I can move \startcontents after \addcontentsline, but this would not really solve my problem as I have several such chapters.
So ... a solution could be:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\titleblock}{
    \@ifundefined{c@ttl@toc@default}{}{
        \stopcontents
    }
    \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Foo}
    \startcontents
    \printcontents{l}{1}{}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\titleblock

\section{Bar}

%===

\titleblock

\section{Bar}

\end{document}

But the output in the .plc file still looks quite messy ... and it does not explain the reason for the error about \ttll@chapter.

I got the solution. We know that the error tells us something about \ttll@chapter and a missing number at this place. When studying the package source code, we find the following snippet:
% General commands. A level register. Explicit numbers
% because they are used in csnames. Ignored if already defined.

\ifx\ttll@section\@undefined

  \@ifundefined{chapter}
    {\def\ttll@part{0}}
    {\def\ttll@part{-1}%
     \def\ttll@chapter{0}}
  \def\ttll@section{1}
  \def\ttll@subsection{2}
  \def\ttll@subsubsection{3}
  \def\ttll@paragraph{4}
  \def\ttll@subparagraph{5}

\fi

So the problem really is that I tried to add a TOC entry for a chapter using the article class where this is not defined per default and which is also reflected in the above code snippet. So a simple solution is to just use the report class:
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\startcontents

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Foo}

\printcontents{l}{1}{}

\section{Bar}

\end{document}


The “internal TOC” is called the “bookmarks”.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\begin{document}

\startcontents

\bookmark[level=0,page=\thepage]{Foo}

\printcontents{l}{1}{}

\section{Bar}

\end{document}



Thanks, that is actually a good hint! I don't know why I overlooked this nice package.
